# Concatenating String in LINQ-to-Entities

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

This code works if I take out

> - " " + p.MIDDLE_NAME

Thus the remaining code looks like:

> p.FIRST_NAME + " " + p.LAST_NAME

Maybe LINQ-to-Entities just doesn't support concatenating more than two strings at a time?

```
    Protected Sub btnFilter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFilter.Click
    Dim dbContext As Campus6Entities = New Campus6Entities
    Using dbContext
        Dim find_students = From p In dbContext.PEOPLE _
                            Let Full_Name = p.FIRST_NAME + " " + p.MIDDLE_NAME + " " + p.LAST_NAME _
                            Where Full_Name = txtFilterText.Text _
                            Select p.FIRST_NAME, p.MIDDLE_NAME, p.LAST_NAME, p.PEOPLE_CODE_ID

        rptrFilteredStudents.DataSource = find_students
        rptrFilteredStudents.DataBind()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm assuming SQL Server as the database?

Comment: @dave: in that case you should start using your version control system more often. This is one of the things that makes it unthinkable for me to work without a VCS where I can commit very often.

Comment: Yes, it is SQL Server, though I'm using the Entity Framework v 4 as the ORM.

Comment: @martinho I usually do...I didn't think I was making a significant change. :P

Comment: Not a big VB guy, but what happens if you use `&` instead of `+` when concatenating the strings? I don't know if there is an actual difference there, but it might be worth a shot. And in case you were wondering, I've used a 3rd party tool to connect to an Oracle database using Entity Framework, and experienced query issues at runtime, so that's why I wanted to confirm SQL Server.

Comment: Is `MIDDLE_NAME` really of type string? What's the exact exception?

Comment: @Joe: nah, those are equivalent. The compiler will turn that into a call to Concat anyway.

Comment: To corroborate my guess below, does `p.FIRST_NAME + p.MIDDLE_NAME + p.LAST_NAME` work (no spaces, just three values)? And `p.FIRST_NAME + p.MIDDLE_NAME + p.LAST_NAME + p.MIDDLE_NAME` (no spaces, four values)? And `p.FIRST_NAME + p.MIDDLE_NAME + p.LAST_NAME + p.MIDDLE_NAME + p.LAST_NAME` (no spaces, five values)?

Comment: Workaround #1: Don't accept your name in a single textbox, but rather use three of them, then you can compare the columns one at a time. This is probably a better solution anyway, because your code will break on a person with no middle name anyway.

Comment: Workaround #2: Use a custom SQL statement or stored proc - you can still access the connection using your Entity Framework connection.

Comment: @Joe - May I ask what 3rd party tool you have used to connect to Oracle using EF?

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed: We used DevArt dotConnect - it worked pretty well, and was not unreasonably priced. It worked for all of our basic needs, but there were a few things that just didn't translate properly into Oracle - I can't remember what they were, but they were definitely edge cases, and there's a good chance that they've fixed it since then anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here's a guess. I just typed this into LinqPad:

```
From x in Enumerable.Empty(Of String)().AsQueryable()
Select x + " " + x
```

And got this as the equivalent expression tree (sorry, LinqPad show this C#-y):

```
System.String[]
   .Select (x => String.Concat (x, " ", x))
```

Then I typed this:

```
From x in Enumerable.Empty(Of String)().AsQueryable()
Select x + " " + x
```

And the expression tree became:

```
System.String[]
   .Select (x => String.Concat (new String[] { x, " ", x, " ", x } ))
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that `Concat` has overloads for up to four parameters, and then there is an overload that takes a parameter array. Maybe the LINQ provider does not support that last one.

EDIT: According to [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/168e855f-45d3-4655-ad8b-3689982f21bc/) LINQ to entities does not current support `string.Concat` with something other than strings.

Answer (score 1):

I got something similar working like this - in C# but the solution should work in VB too:

```
string.Concat(string.Concat(p.FIRST_NAME, " ", p.MIDDLE_NAME, " "), p.LAST_NAME)
```

It doesn't support over 4 items so you have to nest them.